# Catch table lock exception for sql anywhere ado.net

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqlanywhere, table-lock

What is the best way, to catch a table lock exception with ado.net and `iAnywhere.Data.SqlAnywhere.EF6`? My problem is, that `command.ExecuteNonQuery` cause a `SAException` which contains the message, that a user has locked all rows in a table.

The problem is, that it is a general `SAException`, not a specific one like `SATableLockException`, which would be nice.

Now the question: how to detect without using the error message, that the error is a table lock exception?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looking at the SQL Anywhere 16 NET API reference I can't find a SATableLockException, therefore I'm not sure if it is possible to detect the error without looking at the SAError list of the Errors property of the SAException class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution for this. I just cast the exception to `SAException` and userd the Error-Code property (thank you @tzup):

Example:

```
try
{
    // Maybe some sa-exception occurse
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException)
    {
        var saException = (iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException)ex;

        // Only catch table locks
        if (saException.NativeError == -210 || saException.ErrorCode == -210
             || saException.NativeError == -1281 || saException.ErrorCode == -1281)
        {
            // Table lock here!
        }
    }
    else { // do some thing else... }
}
```